# Brother refuses to print claiming there is no ink, but there is ink

Tags: printer, ink, brother-printer

My Brother printer (MFCJ4420DW) does not want to print. It says that "there is not enough ink to maintain print quality" and shows that the black and yellow ink cartridges are empty. I took them out and saw that they are not empty - each of them is about 20% full.

How can I tell Brother to continue printing with the remaining ink?

Alternatively, I would like to install only black ink cartridge and leave the yellow empty. How can I tell Brother to ignore the empty yellow cartridge and print with black only?

Comment: Most of the time printer firmware won't wail till there is no ink at all to warn you. It has to make sure there is enough ink to maintain quality and security (yes running out of ink can cause damage because of heating). People sometimes tinker with cartridges and make them keep printing after warning but it's highly risky. I would suggest getting replacements.

Comment: Did you refill the cartridges, or are they new cartridges? Some inkjekt printers have chips in the cartridges that measure consumption, so refilling doesn't work. The ultimate solution is "don't buy inkjet printers that use those tactics".

Comment: @dirkt that's a good idea. How can I know which printers use such tactics?